# How to get the home directory of a sudoed user from ansible_env?

Tags: ansible

When I sudo as a user the ansible_env does not have the correct **HOME** variable set - **"/root"**. However, if I echo the HOME env variable it is correct - **"/var/lib/pgsql"**. Is there no other way to get the home directory of a sudo'ed user?

Also, I have already set **"sudo_flags = -H"** in ansible.cfg and I cannot login as postgres user.

```
- name: ansible_env->HOME
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: postgres
  debug: msg="{{ ansible_env.HOME }}"

- name: echo $HOME
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: postgres
  shell: "echo $HOME"
  register: postgres_homedir

- name: postgres_homedir.stdout
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: postgres
  debug: msg="{{ postgres_homedir.stdout }}"
```

Result:

```
TASK: [PostgreSQL | ansible_env->HOME] **************************************** 
ok: [postgres] => {
    "msg": "/root"
}

TASK: [PostgreSQL | echo $HOME] *********************************************** 
changed: [postgres]

TASK: [PostgreSQL | postgres_homedir.stdout] ********************************** 
ok: [postgres] => {
    "msg": "/var/lib/pgsql"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can replicate the output above by running the playbook as the root user (either locally with `- hosts: localhost`, or by SSHing as root). The facts gathered by Ansible are those of the root user.

If this is what you are doing, then your workaround seems to be the best way of getting the postgres user's $HOME variable.

Even though you add `sudo_user: postgres` to the `ansible_env->HOME` task, the fact will not change since it is gathered at the start of the play.

Comment: After going through the docs it looks like my workaround really is the only way. Although, I wish there was a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

"~" expands as the non-root user if you use "become: no".   In the example below I combine that with an explicit "sudo" to do something as root in the home directory:

```
- name: Setup | install
  command: sudo make install chdir=~/git/emacs
  become: no
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear whether my problem was the same way around, but in case its useful:

I had a play running with `become: yes` (no other `become_` options set, so using sudo) but wanted to do something in the "real" `ansible_user`'s (rocky) homedir. What seems to work is this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ansible_user: rocky
  tasks:
    - setup:
        gather_subset: env
      become: no # <-- IMPORTANT
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}" # = /home/rocky
```